# Setting the name of an index with makeidx and adding to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, naming

I would like to change the name of my index, so that instead of "Index", it reads "Index of whatever I want". I've tried quite a few things:

- redefining `\indexname`, after or before calling `\makeindex`
- using the `index` package and calling `\newindex` instead of `\makeindex`

None of these worked.

Also, I'm trying to add the index to the ToC, but it doesn't get linked properly. From what I understand the contentsline should be called inside the `.ind` but this file is generated by `makeindex`. How can I do that?

Comment: It would be better to show your recent efforts by a [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl). There can be several probable causes for your problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=What?,intoc]

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{A}
a\index{a}
\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

You can give **imakeidx** the `original` option, if you don't like using **multicol** for balancing the columns in the final index page. The package supports multiple indices, with possibly different number of columns.

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors.)

Comment: This is perfect thanks. Is it a new package? I couldn't find it in TeXLive on Ubuntu Natty.

Comment: @Raphink: it's almost one year old, but unfortunately TeX Live/Ubuntu is still the 2009 edition. Also **idxlayout** is probably missing; notice that the two packages are compatible with each other (only load lockstep's one after **imakeidx**).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the [`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) package. Use the `unbalanced` option to switch off balancing the columns. (Disclosure: I'm the package author.)

EDIT: Note that because `idxlayout` is based on [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol), indexes in the `article` class (and other classes without the `\chapter` sectioning command) will basically behave like a normal `\section*`, i.e., they won't start on a new page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% Variant A
% \renewcommand{\indexname}{Index of whatever I want}

% Variant B
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand*{\indexname}{Index of whatever I want}
}

\usepackage[totoc]{idxlayout}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First}

Some text about foo.\index{foo}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
  \renewcommand{\indexname}{Register}
}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \section{Foo}
    Item\index{Item}

  \printindex
\end{document}
```

The [tocbibind](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package is for inserting several lists (LoF, LoT, …) into the ToC.