# Outputting parameter of \index

Tags: indexing

When I indicate an index entry using `\index` I have to type the text of the indexed word twice, in context and as a parameter of `\index`:

```
 This is an index: Hello! \index{Hello} And ....
```

And when I decide to change the indexed word I have to make the change for two words.
How can I force TeX to output the parameter of `\index` ? (Perhaps `\index*`!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`index`](http://ctan.org/pkg/index) package provides the starred version `\index*` that both typesets its argument and adds it to the index; there's also the [`hvindex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hvindex) package and its `\Index` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{index}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some text about \index*{foo}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hvindex}

\begin{document}

Some text about \Index{foo}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

And if you want to do without additional packages, you could save the original version of `\index` and include it in a redefinition that does what you want. (The following example assumes that `\index` *doesn't* feature an optional argument.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand*{\index}[1]{#1\oldindex{#1}}

\begin{document}

Some text about \index{foo}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I seem to have spotted a bug in `hvindex`: A spurious space is added after `\Index` & friends, apparently because comment signs are missing at the end of various lines in the source code. The following patch corrects this behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hvindex}

% The following must NOT be enclosed in `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`
\def\IndexXXi#1@#2@#3\IndexNIL{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax %              no @ in last arg
    \def\hvTemp{#1}%
    \ifx\hvTemp\hvEncap\index{{#1}}#1\else% {{...}} to get "| with hyperref
      \ifx\hvIDXfont\hvIDXfontDefault\index{#1}#1% <-- THIS COMMENT SIGN WAS MISSING
      \else\index{#1@\hvIDXfont{#1}}\hvIDXfont{#1}\fi\fi%#1
  \else\index{#1@#2}#2\fi}%     % #1@#2
%
\def\IndexXXii#1!#2@#3@#4\IndexNIL{%
  \ifx\relax#3\relax        %       no @ in last arg
    \def\hvTemp{#2}%
    \ifx\hvTemp\hvEncap\index{#1!{#2}}#2\else
      \ifx\hvIDXfont\hvIDXfontDefault\index{#2}#2% <-- THIS ONE, TOO
      \else\index{#1!#2@\hvIDXfont{#2}}\hvIDXfont{#2}\fi\fi%
  \else\index{#1!\protect#2@#3}#3\fi}
%
\def\IndexXXiii#1!#2!#3@#4@#5\IndexNIL{%
  \ifx\relax#4\relax        %       no @ in last arg
    \def\hvTemp{#3}%
    \ifx\hvTemp\hvEncap\index{#1!#2!{#3}}#3\else
      \ifx\hvIDXfont\hvIDXfontDefault\index{#3}#3% <-- AND THIS ONE, TOO
      \else\index{#1!#2!#3@\hvIDXfont{#3}}\hvIDXfont{#3}\fi\fi%
  \else\index{#1!#2!\protect#3@#4}#4\fi}

\begin{document}

Some text about \Index{foo}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Thanks, Which is better any why?

Comment: @Reza That depends. :-) If you're using a non-standard document class, the `index` package may be problematic. Simply redefining `\index` yourself may fail if you have multiple indexes (and an `\index` command with optional argument).

Comment: How can I change the title of index section produced by index package. (I want translate "Index" word to Persian )

Comment: @Reza See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19268/setting-the-name-of-an-index-with-makeidx-and-adding-to-table-of-contents

Comment: That solution do not work with \index package

Comment: @Reza `\usepackage{index}\makeindex\renewindex{default}{idx}{ind}{My Index Name}`

Comment: @Reza But my last comment *is*. Perhaps you should ask a new question at the main site.

Comment: @Herbert Please have a look at my edited answer.