# How do I pass the index style file to makeindex using arara?

Tags: indexing, glossaries, arara

I am running `arara` like this:

`% arara: makeindex: { options: -s "%tm.ist" -t "%tm.glg" -o "%tm.gls" "tm.glo" }`

to produce glossaries with the package `gloassaries`. I took this options from my IDE settings, where they have been working.

Now, when running `arara`, it stops telling me:

```
Running MakeIndex... 

Index style file %tm.ist not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
FAILURE
make: *** [ararabuild] Fehler 1
```

Sorry, but that is too cryptic for me. What is happening? `main.ist` does exist in the main folder.

Comment: Why not using `arara: makeglossaries`?

Comment: Because I didn't know of it. Thanks. But `makeglossaries` just takes one argument. I am writing a glossary, acronymlist and symbolslist (or trying it) and the command above has always been my working process. In my preamble I am having  `\makeglossaries`. What would be the right command to run this?

Comment: The `arara` directive runs the helper script `makeglossaries` that takes care automatically of all declared glossaries defined through the package.

Comment: Oh, cool. That's kicking out a lot of commands I didn't understand. It works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to pass complicated options to MakeIndex in order to prepare glossaries defined through the `glossaries` package (including list of acronyms or symbols).

The script `makeglossaries` automagically does all the work; if your main file is `main.tex`, running

```
makeglossaries main
```

will do. For `arara`, the directive

```
% arara: makeglossaries
```

is the way to go.

Comment: BTW it does `makeindex` as well. So one arara line for several glossaries and indices. Cool. Two offtopics: could you link your post of explaining imakeidx again (it has been deleted above)! Are backrefs in imakeidx a planed future feature?

Comment: The link is http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19269/4427. Back references and indices are quite different things.

Comment: No, there was a longer post. You explaining the "history" of making indices in LaTeX. Ok, back references is the wrong word. I meant a hyperref page number next to the index entry.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Just load `hyperref` after `imakeidx` and page numbers will be links.